# Java8 convert List of Map to List of string

Tags: java, java-8

I am using Java8 to achieve the below things,

```
 Map<String, String> m0 = new HashMap<>();
        m0.put("x", "123");
        m0.put("y", "456");
        m0.put("z", "789");

        Map<String, String> m1 = new HashMap<>();
        m1.put("x", "000");
        m1.put("y", "111");
        m1.put("z", "222");

        List<Map<String, String>> l = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(m0, m1));

        List<String> desiredKeys = Lists.newArrayList("x");

        List<Map<String, String>> transformed = l.stream().map(map -> map.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(e -> desiredKeys.stream().anyMatch(k -> k.equals(e.getKey())))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), p -> p.getValue())))
                .filter(m -> !m.isEmpty())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.err.println(l);
        System.err.println(transformed);
        List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Map<String,String> map : transformed) {
            values.add(map.values().toString());
            System.out.println("Values inside map::"+map.values());
        }
        System.out.println("values::"+values); //values::[[123], [000]]
```

Here, I would like to fetch only the x-values from the list. I have achieved it but it is not in a proper format.

Expected output:
values::[123, 000]

Actual output:
values::[[123], [000]]

I know how to fix the actual output. But is there any easy way to achieve this issue? Any help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need to iterate over the entire map to find an entry by its key.  That's what `Map.get` is for.  To flatten the list of list of values, use `flatMap`:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;
.....

List<String> values = l.stream()
    .flatMap(x -> desiredKeys.stream()
            .filter(x::containsKey)
            .map(x::get)
    ).collect(toList());
```

On a side note, avoid using `l` (lower case L) as a variable name.  It looks too much like the number `1`.

Comment: is it possible fetch "y" value based on "x" key?

Comment: @VelNaga can you clarify that?  What do you want the output to be?

Comment: If the X-value is present in the map then return Y-value.For ex) take 1st map, I will check for "x" value "123" if it is present then return Y value "456"

Comment: So if the map contains both key "x" and key "y" you want to return the value for key "y"?

Comment: Yep based on x-value

Comment: This is different from the logic in your question.  Given that there are already several answers addressing the question as asked initially, you should start a new question and explain your desired logic more clearly

Comment: That's true. Change of requirement all the time.Thanks a lot for your answer. Let me find a way for my problem.

Answer (score 3):

I’m not sure Streams will help, here.  It’s easier to just loop through the Maps:

```
Collection<String> values = new ArrayList<>();

for (Map<String, String> map : l) {
    Map<String, String> copy = new HashMap<>(map);
    copy.keySet().retainAll(desiredKeys);
    values.addAll(copy.values());
}
```

Comment: Alone the usage of both views makes this more elegant than streams, would upvote if I had some left :)

Comment: It might be expensive to copy the entire map first, if the number of desired keys is significantly smaller than the original map sizes. Your solution has a point if the source maps are mutable and their original content is not required, so that no copy is required.

Comment: @Holger Copying the entire Map means copying only references to the keys and values.  It’s not a lot of memory usage, relatively speaking, even for large Maps.

Comment: Unfortunately, it’s not that simple. `HashMap` does not only create an array under the hood, but an `Entry` instance for every mapping. Still, I was actually focusing on the CPU expenses, as `HashMap` has no cheap way of transferring mappings, even if the source is already an instance of `HashMap`. So copying an entire map implies hashing all entries, as opposed to looking up each desired key only.

Comment: is it possible fetch "y" value based on "x" key?

Comment: I don’t understand.  Can you give an example?

Answer (score 3):

Flat map over the stream of maps to get a single stream representing the map entries of all your input maps. From there, you can filter out each entry whose key is not contained in the desired keys. Finally, extract the equivalent value of each entry to collect them into a list.

```
final List<String> desiredValues = l.stream()
    .map(Map::entrySet)
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .filter(entry -> desiredKeys.contains(entry.getKey()))
    .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**EDIT**

This assumes that if a map has the key "x" it must also has the key "y" so to fetch the corredponding value.

```
final List<String> desiredValues = l.stream()
    .filter(map -> map.containsKey("x"))
    .map(map -> map.get("y"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: is it possible fetch "y" value based on "x" key?

Comment: @VelNaga do you mean fetch entries whose key is "x" and value is "y" ?

Comment: If the map has the value "x" then fetch value of "Y"

Comment: If the X-value is present in the map then return Y-value.For ex) take 1st map, I will check for "x" value "123" if it is present then return Y value "456"